# Scaling a font size without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there a way to scale font-size without using JavaScript? For example if you open the webpage on a 15" laptop and a container div was 400px wide and the font was defined to fill the entire div. Then you open the website on a 17" screen and the div is 600px. Is there a way to make the font automatically scale?

In essence its adding a "width: 100%" to text, which you cant do. I would much rather do it without JavaScript because I am already using a lot in the webpage and it becomes messy after a while.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally you can't rely on the font to fill a given width even if that width does not change. Font rendering differs between browsers and operating systems, so the same text with the same font and the same font size might result in a different pixel width of the rendered text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help everyone, but what I ended up doing was just using text-align: justify. It's not exactly what I wanted, but its a solution to stretch the text. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *media queries* for that. Depending on the width of your page/container you can set the font size accordingly.

For example:

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #container { font-size: 90%; }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    #container { font-size: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give an example?

Comment: How exactly would media queries help scale the font to fit the available ___width___?

Comment: OP asks about a `div` that is 400px vs 600px wide; you seem to assume for some reason that the `div` would fill the entire viewport of the device.

Comment: @lanzz it's *really* easy to calculate the widths to be used in the queries for the `div` of 400px or 600px, since it will take up a defined part of the viewport. If the `div` is 40% of the viewport it's just simple math to calculate the values.

Comment: If the `div` is defined as a percentage of the viewport, but the device has a 500px width, neither of your media queries will be correct for that specific device. You would likely need separate media queries for every single possible device width (and that does not mean only those you _think_ you might be likely to encounter).

Comment: @lanzz media queries don't work like that in the first place. They're applying the changes with widths *from* `n px` *to* `y px` and everything in between. I'm assuming the OP isn't interested in exact 400px and 600px, but more likely (for a sake of example) "from 320 to 480" and "from 480 to 800" accordingly

Comment: Yes, but 40% of 500px is _not_ the same pixel width as 40% of 480px, and isn't the same as 40% of 600px either.

Comment: @lanzz correct - but we're talking about a *range* where the font-size will be the same, i.e. from 400px to 600px and no matter what 40% of those will be

Comment: If the `div` is 40% of the device width, then its width will be different for _all_ device widths between 480px and 600px, and OP wants to size the font in a way that the text fills the _width_ of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Add media queries your css file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
    body
    {
        //font-size or what you want to change 
    }
}
```

Or write external file and import it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.tld/screen.css" type="text/css" media="MediaCssId" />
```